# Command-T won't compile for Vim

Tags: vim

I'm trying to install Command-T for Vim, but no success so far.

I reinstalled vim using brew and the ruby version for vim is 2.5.1

I installed ruby 2.5.1 using RVM, I ran ruby ruby extconf.rb, I got this output

```
checking for float.h... yes
checking for ruby.h... yes
checking for stdlib.h... yes
checking for string.h... yes
checking for fcntl.h... yes
checking for stdint.h... yes
checking for sys/errno.h... yes
checking for sys/socket.h... yes
checking for ruby/st.h... yes
checking for st.h... yes
checking for pthread_create() in -lpthread... yes
creating Makefile
```

then I ran make and got it:

```
compiling ext.c
compiling heap.c
compiling match.c
compiling matcher.c
compiling watchman.c
linking shared-object ext.bundle
```

But when I try to use it on my vim, I got the following message:

```
command-t.vim could not load the C extension.
Please see INSTALLATION and TROUBLE-SHOOTING in the help.
Vim Ruby version: 2.5.1-p57
For more information type:    :help command-t
```

If I use ruby version 2.5.0 to compile, the message says that I got the wrong version of ruby.

I have no idea what else I could do, please help me

Comment: run the command  `:ruby puts "#{RUBY_VERSION}-p#{RUBY_PATCHLEVEL}"` inside vim. What the output of the command?

Comment: @shvetsovdm 2.5.1-p57

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that you have to compile **command-t** **C** extension with the same **ruby** as **vim** compiled.

You mention that you are using **RVM** and that vim compiled with **ruby 2.5.1-p57**. You need to choose exact same **ruby**. If you compile (in your case installed with **brew**) vim with ruby 2.5.1-p57 from **RVM** then run command:

```
$ rvm use 2.5.1-p57
```

Then recompile command-t, make sure `ruby -v` returns 2.5.1-p57:

```
$ ruby -v

$ ruby extconf.rb

$ make
```

If this doesn't helps, probably you installed it with system wide ruby with the same 2.5.1 version. This can solve the issue:

```
$ rvm use system

$ ruby extconf.rb

$ make
```

The idea to compile **command-t** with the same version of **ruby** as **vim** compiled.

In worse case scenario you can reinstall vim.

Also you can reference the [command-t docs](https://github.com/wincent/command-t/blob/master/doc/command-t.txt#L317)

Comment: I was running the same version, but I could solve using rvm use system instead of rvm's version 2.5.1.

Comment: Thank you for the `rvm use system`!

Comment: glad it helped you